# how to count a sequence(pattern) of numbers

Tags: t-sql

I have  table like this

| ID | MW1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 0 |
| 11 | 0 |

My output should look like this

| ID | MW1 | CountSequenz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | 0 | 3 |
| 9 | 1 | 4 |
| 10 | 0 | 5 |
| 11 | 0 | 5 |

Comment: So what is your qusetion? What is stopping **you** from achieving your goal? What (R)DBMS are you using? SQL Server? SyBase? Azure SQL Database? Azure Synapse? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

The window functions would be a nice fit here.

```
Select ID
      ,MW1
      ,Seq = sum(Flg) over (order by ID)
 From  (
        Select * 
              ,Flg =case when lag(MW1,1) over (order by ID)=MW1 then 0 else 1 end
        From YourTable
       ) A     
Order by ID
```

**Results**

[image]